# Android Activity.onResume not been called

Tags: android

I got `singleTask` activity

```
<activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

This is my start intent.

```
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    showIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(startIntent);
```

In MyActivity I get onNewItent called. But activity is not launched and onResume is not called.

Also if I call this code again for second time it worked as expected: onResume is called and onNewIntent right after it.

What can it be?

Comment: is the signature of onResume correct ?

Comment: yeah, its some thing else

Comment: can you post the whole code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514405/oncreate-not-called

Comment: can you please share the whole code?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Tim In my case the activity is not lunched at all. I do very similar thing, from click event I lunch MyActivity