# Bottom navigation view does not appear in emulator, only in layout preview

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

The navigation bottom view is not showing I do not see anything wrong with the code, although it shows in the preview.
Once the main activity has been launched it does not show.
Note that I am starting the main activity with the bottom navigation view within a launching activity that checks whether the user logged in.

This is the launching activity layout file

```
package io.keepcoding.androidfinalproject.ui

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import io.keepcoding.androidfinalproject.R
import io.keepcoding.androidfinalproject.ui.auth.AuthActivity
import io.keepcoding.androidfinalproject.ui.main.MainActivity

class LaunchingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var userLoggedIn: Boolean = true
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch)
        if(userLoggedIn){
            startAppActivity()
        } else {
            startAuthActivity()
        }
    }

    private fun startAuthActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, AuthActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    private fun startAppActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

This is the launching activity layout file that is not shown, because as soon as the app starts if the user is logged in, main activity is started.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.LaunchingActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my main activity layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/app_bar"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_bar_unselected"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my main activity code

```
package io.keepcoding.androidfinalproject.ui.main

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.replace
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import io.keepcoding.androidfinalproject.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var toolbar: ActionBar
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        toolbar = supportActionBar!!
        val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = navigationView
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_products -> {
                toolbar.title = "Products"
                val productFragment = ProductsFragment.newInstance()
                openFragment(productFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_map -> {
                toolbar.title = "Map"
                val mapFragment = ProductsFragment.newInstance()
                openFragment(mapFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                toolbar.title = "Profile"
                val profileFragment = ProductsFragment.newInstance()
                openFragment(profileFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                toolbar.title = "Notifications"
                val notificationsFragment = ProductsFragment.newInstance()
                openFragment(notificationsFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Here is the menu layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_products"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_products"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/title_products" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/title_map" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sell"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/title_sell"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/title_profile"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications" />

</menu>
```

You can find a link to the project here

https://github.com/kcFinalProject/AndroidFinalProject/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Your activity_main.xml is the one that has the nav bar right?

If that's the case, maybe your issue is that the Frame Layour height is `match_parent`

To see if this is the problem, set the frame layout visibility to invisible

Add to the FrameLayout the property `android:visibility="invisible"` and then see if the nav bar is visible.

If the nav bar is visible now, then you have to set the bottom constraints of the FrameLayout at the top of the nav bar. Add another property to the FrameLayout `android:layout_above="@id/navigationView"`

Answer (score 0):

It is solved, I was overriding the wrong onCreate method, so the main activity being started from within Launching activity never actually run.

[onCreate not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514405/oncreate-not-called)